# Properly use a singleton in objective c

Tags: core-data, singleton, global-variables

I´m lost on this one, already read some things all over the internet but my problem is that i need to understand how to properly use the singleton. My problem is, at some point in my app i do what is below:

```
myVariable = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Entity" 
          inManagedObjectContext:context];
```

I need to preserve `myVariable` and use it in other views, and i read somewhere that this is the best way if i want to use a variable through all my views. I have followed this example but i really don´t know how to use it, can someone explain it to me?:

```
@interface DataLoader : NSObject {
   NSString *someProperty; 
   //(i think i need myVariable here, and not type NSString)
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *someProperty;

+ (id)sharedManager;
@end


@implementation DataLoader

+(id)sharedInstance  {
   static dispatch_once_t p=0;
   __strong static id _sharedObject = nil;
   dispatch_once(&p, ^{
    _sharedObject = [[self alloc]init];
   });

return _sharedObject;
}

@end
```

How can i set myVariable and then in another views use it?

Regards

Comment: I don't think you quite know what you're doing, and using a singleton will not fix that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The usual way is to have the controllers pass the variable on to the next one whenever they are pushed on the navigation stack, e.g. `in prepareForSegue:`. Just give your view controllers a strong `@property` to keep track of it.

```
SomeViewController *nextVC = segue.destinationController;
nextVC.myVariable = self.myVariable;
```

That is how it is done in many instances of Apple's sample code with managed object context,  it certainly is good pattern.

Comment: Hello Mundi, thanks for you answer. I have seen that solution, but how do you use it if you are in a master detail application? i´m asking this because every time you use the master button you are always direct to master view class. All segues are connected to it, and if you have many views, you cannot force passing from view A to B to pass the value...you can be on A and go to D...what happens to the value that i want to preserve?. Sorry i´m a new on this one, i never had the need to use this.Can you give me a hint? Thanks

Comment: That's exactly how it works. In `prepareForSegue` you can distinguish the segues by identifier and pass the variables accordingly.

Comment: Hello Mundi, sorry for the late answer, i´m going to use the prepareforsegue method in master view class. Thanks for you help. Regards